# Deployed flask_injector dependent project to Lambda doesn't work

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zappa, flask-injector

I'm trying to deploy a python project uses `flask_restplus` and `flask_injector` packages to AWS Lambda using [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) project, but it doesn't work, it throws an error when I try to call the API gateway that Zappa automatically created for the project:

> [ERROR] AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/var/task/handler.py", line 602, in lambda_handler
>       return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
>     File "/var/task/handler.py", line 245, in lambda_handler
>       handler = cls()
>     File "/var/task/handler.py", line 139, in **init**
>       self.app_module = importlib.import_module(self.settings.APP_MODULE)
>     File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>     File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>     File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>     File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>     File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
>     File "", line 728, in exec_module
>     File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>     File "/var/task/app.py", line 1, in 
>       from startup import Startup
>     File "/var/task/startup.py", line 3, in 
>       from flask_injector import FlaskInjector
>     File "/var/task/flask_injector.py", line 13, in 
>       from typing import Any, Callable, cast, Dict, get_type_hints, Iterable, List, TypeVar, Union
>     File "/var/task/typing.py", line 1357, in 
>       class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
>     File "/var/task/typing.py", line 1005, in **new**
>       self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry

The project consists of two Python files only:

- app.py:

```py
from startup import Startup

app = Startup.start_app()
```

- startup.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api
# if I removed the following line, the project works perfectly.
from flask_injector import FlaskInjector

class Startup():
    @staticmethod
    def start_app():
        appObj = Flask(__name__)
        appObj.secret_key = '123123'
        app = appObj

        print("It's working")

        return app
```

And the `zappa_settings.json` file

```
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "app.app",
        "aws_region": "[My Region]",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "my-api-test",
        "runtime": "python3.7",
        "s3_bucket": "[An S3 bucket name]",
        "keep_warm": false,
        "memory_size": 1024,
        "timeout_seconds": 90,
        "manage_roles": false,
        "role_name": "[A specific role name to deploy the project]",
        "role_arn": "[Role ARN]"
    }
}
```

I don't know what's the issue here, why using `flask_injector` causes this error?

Answer (score 2):

After more investigation on the issue, and reading an answer from Amazon:
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/191460/ask-sdk-for-python-14-possible-issue-when-deployed.html

I figured out that one of my dependencies installs the package `typing` (which can be found as standard python package), and by removing it the problem solved.

So just do:

```
pip uninstall typing
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: When using Pip version 20.1 (released 29/04/2020), the solution of uninstalling the `typing` package no longer works for some reason. An easy workaround is to ensure you're using the previous version of Pip, 20.0.2, where this solution still works.